# Lagrangian for a rigid-flexible pendulum

Tags: homework-and-exercises, lagrangian-formalism

Given the set up in the figure and assuming the green mass has an initial angular velocity (ω_0), can I use Lagrangian mechanics to derive equations of motion of the system?

My initial thought was that I can somehow manipulate/add new terms to the Lagrangian for a double pendulum and proceed from there. Any ideas would be very much appreciated :)

[image]

Description of system:

Flexible beam (Young's modulus = E, second moment of area = I, mass = m2, length = L2), with a point mass (M) on the end, connected to a rigid beam (mass = m1, length = L1) such that the there is no relative angular displacement between the rigid beam and the start of the flexible beam. The rigid beam is then connected to a rotational damper with damping coefficient c.

Comment: I think you want to do it with constraints. That probably means you want to learn about Lagrange multipliers.  I suspect it may be a non-trivial effort, but not impossible.